# Styling WordPress login page - Can I change the markup on the login page?

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I'm trying to make the login-page prettier, but there are several things that makes it difficult (read: impossible).

I know that there are a bazillion plugins that can do some of the things, - but they're all just 'painting over' WordPress' standard login screen. And I would like to make it clean, - instead of converting my login into some patchwork-project.

Can I write my own markup for the login screen, without modifying the core code-base?

---

### What I want to change

Here's a list of most of the things that I'm trying to do. Some of which I have found ways to make. And most of them are quite terrible...

1. **Logo**: The logo on the login-screen links to `#`. I want it to link to the main login-screen (so it can be pressed from the 'Forgotten login'-page.
2. **Username-text**: Be able to change 'Username or Email' to 'Email' without having to use the `gettext`-hook and write a whole function for that small change.
3. **Better code for input-fields**: Here's what the code looks like for the labels/input-fields:

```
<p>
    <label for="user_login">Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" autocapitalize="off"></label>
  </p>
```

... I want to add a class-name to the paragraph, remove the `<br>, add a span around 'Email'. And maybe even leave the label blank, and moving the 'Email'-text outside the``-tag (for custom styling).

4. **Better return-text on forgotten password-page**: On the 'Forgotten password'-page, in the bottom, then this link here links back the main login-page:

```
<p id="nav">
    <a href="https://example.org/wp-login.php">Log in</a>
</p>
```

... It should either be 'Back to login' or 'Return to login-screen' or something that makes more sense.

5. **Be able to changing the order of things**: I want to have the option of moving the 'Forgotten password'-link up above the 'Log in'-button.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a Codex page on this exact subject: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

The Codex is always a good place to start!

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. But that page there explains how to convert my project to a patchwork with a bunch of CSS-trivia and functions for replacing singular things (such as the logo and texts). I'm looking for at way where I can rewrite the entire markup for the login-page - or a good way for dealing with the 5 listed issues, which that page doesn't explain.

Comment: Well, if you read all the way down you will come to this bit: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page